# How to implement bucketsort in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a test program to develop an implementation of bucket sort for personal development. The examples that I have seen online do not match the sort of implementation that I am trying to accomplish.

My attempt

```
import java.util.*;

public class BucketSort {
    private static int t = 10;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] list = {331, 454, 230, 34, 343, 45, 59, 453, 345, 231, 9};
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            System.out.print(list[i]+" ");
        }
        bucketSort(list);
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            System.out.print(list[i]+" ");
        }
    }

    public static <E> void bucketSort(int[] list) {
        java.util.ArrayList<Integer>[] bucket = new java.util.ArrayList[t+1];// Distribute the elements from list to buckets
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            // Assume element has the getKey() method
            int key = list[i]; // list[i].getKey()
        if (bucket[(int) key] == null)
            bucket[(int) key] = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();
            bucket[(int) key].add(list[i]);
        }
        // Now move the elements from the buckets back to list
        int k = 0; // k is an index for list
        for (int i = 0; i < bucket.length; i++) {
            if (bucket[i] != null) {
                for (int j = 0; j < bucket[i].size(); j++)
                    list[k++] = (int)(bucket[i].get(j));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected:
a sorted list of integers

Actual:

```
java BucketSort 
331 454 230 34 343 45 59 453 345 231 9 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 331 out of bounds for length 11
        at BucketSort.bucketSort(BucketSort.java:21)
        at BucketSort.main(BucketSort.java:10)
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: The indentation of the first `if` in the `bucketSort` method is wrong and it only has a one-line body. Are you sure that code is what you meant?

Comment: `bucket[(int) key] == null` is throwing error as your bucket size is length of `list`+1 & not maximum value present of list. Moreover even if we fix that, your code is creating new list for each new element & hence it won't be able to give you sort result as you are expecting.

Comment: I think the problem is that you cannot assume the `getKey()` method and have to implement such a method according to the order you want to achieve. This function has to map each element to the correct bucket (0 to T). The most basic case would be sorting by the last digit, where your `getKey()` method would simply do `key = item % 10`. Then each list item with a zero in the end would be placed into bucket zero. Items inside buckets are stil not sorted after this. If you want to sort the whole list you have to then sort the individual buckets again before concatenating them to the final list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what bucket sort is but as far as I look at your method, see `bucket[(int) key]` which may result in out of the index exception as happened in your output. Because in the first loop iteration of the for loop you get index `0` corresponding to `list[0]`, that is, `bucket[336]`. However, your being passed array's size is `11`.

If the array's max-valued element is not too high, you can find max element in the array and pass it as a value to the method to define the `bucket` arrays' size instead of `t+1`.